# Trying to add a javascript function to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button

I'm relatively new to HTML so please bear with me. I'm trying to add a simple javascript function that was already provided to me that grabs images from Flickr  to a button. When I click the button, nothing happens. I'm not sure where the error is occuring but I think it has something to do with the function not executing correctly.

**HTML:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>getJSON</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() 
    {  //Functions don't need names. This function will simply run when the page loads
      var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
      $.getJSON( flickerAPI, 
      {  // The "$" simply refers to jQuery. This calls the getJSON function that is found inside jquery-3.1.1.min.js
        tags: "Baruch College", //Some filter information in the format set by Flickr, who owns the JSON
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
      })
        .done(function( data ) 
        { //Here, a an unnamed function is created made into the event handler for the "done" event... in other words, this is the code that will manifest itself when the getJSON is done.
          $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) 
          {
            $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#images" );
            if ( i === 5 ) 
            {
              return false;
            }
          });
        });
    }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I uploaded the jquery script mentioned in the HTML: http://pastebin.com/2CfRNkvq

Comment: you have to run your page on your local server.

Comment: what is the server it's currently running on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where the images will be placed after they are retrieved. In the JavaScript code, you can see that for each image, it creates an `<img>` tag and appends it to the element with `id="images"`.

Just add `id="images"` to the button element like this:

`<button onclick="myFunction()" id="images">Click me</button>`

When you click the button, the images will be placed inside the button.